# Migration MYSQL to ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

right now am working on database migration from `MYSQL` TO `ORACLE`.

I have experience in `MySQL` but not in `Oracle`, So help me to convert the following MYSQL query to `ORACLE`

Mysql query:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as min_id, Server_Name
FROM details
WHERE Server_Role IS NOT NULL THEN
GROUP BY Server_Name
```

Comment: `name` is not a reserved word in Oracle? `role` also?

Comment: that's server name and server role just i removed word server

Comment: Does that query really execute on MySQL? I'd expect syntax error. (`THEN` ...)

Comment: @vimalkumar . . . You can port it as is into any database.  All will give an error on the `THEN`.  A syntax error is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
Just Don't use the THEN clause its not needed.

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS "min_id", Server_Name 
FROM details 
WHERE Server_Role IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Server_Name;
```

Comment: Point out the difference!

Comment: Thank's it worked for me,but may i know the reason why we can't use "then"

Comment: @vimalkumar THEN is generally used when there is IF.
Kindly accept the answer.